# Running cross compiled valgrind on arm docker image

Tags: c++, docker, arm, cross-compiling, valgrind

My aim is to run cross compiled valgrind on an arm emulated environment.
I have cross-compiled valgrind 3.13 using the arm-linaro toolchain(http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2016.02/arm-linux-gnueabi/) with command:

1. ./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi  --host=armv7-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/karan/valgrind/build CFLAGS=-static CPPFLAGS=-fPIC CFLAGS=-fPIC
2. make && make install

I have transferred the valgrind build folder on the docker container( docker image: *https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/ubuntu*
in directory= */root/valgrind/build*) and exported the PATH environment variable as well as VALGRIND_LIB variable.
After this when I try to run valgrind I get the output:

```
valgrind: no program specified
valgrind: Use --help for more information.
```

I created a simple demo file(try.cpp) which prints a string and compiled it on the docker itself with command = **g++ try.cpp**

```
//try.cpp
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
        std::cout<<"HELLO";
        return 0;
}
```

the linker used is the default one and the output of command = **ldd a.out** is

```
root@d170b9f5fc84:~# ldd a.out
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xfe664000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xfe63b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xfe53d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xfe4d4000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xfefc5000)
```

However on running valgrind on this simple demo file, I get the error:

```
root@d170b9f5fc84:~#  valgrind ./a.out
==4064== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4064== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4064== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4064== Command: ./a.out
==4064==

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strcmp
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-armhf.so.3
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-armhf.so.3
valgrind:
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:
valgrind:  Note that if you are debugging a 32 bit process on a
valgrind:  64 bit system, you will need a corresponding 32 bit debuginfo
valgrind:  package (e.g. libc6-dbg:i386).
valgrind:
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

I installed libc6-dbg ( command **apt-get install libc6-dbg**) but to no avail. I am still getting the same error. I thought of replacing the default linker in /lib/ directory (ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -> ld-2.31.so) with the linker provided in toolchain because it had the .symtab section but that broke the OS itself and then I couldn't run any commands on bash.
Could someone tell me how to run valgrind on the arm docker.? I believe My replacement of loader is not correct or incomplete.